# Is Lambda Still Supported In Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, lambda

Only one or two years ago, I remember reading Python constructs that would be removed from Python -- reduce was one of them -- and other constructs that would be emphasized like comprehensions and generators. I saw a very nice description of how Python could be made more functional [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-prog/index.html), and I was wondering on which list lambda appeared, supported or soon-not-to-be supported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lambda` is *not* deprecated, and will continue to be part of the language. Attempts have been made to find an alternative, but nothing fruitful ever came from that.

Quoting a [post by Guido van Rossum in 2006](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/060415.html):

> After so many attempts to come up with an alternative for lambda,
>   perhaps we should admit defeat. I've not had the time to follow the
>   most recent rounds, but I propose that we keep lambda, so as to stop
>   wasting everybody's talent and time on an impossible quest.

`reduce()` was moved to the `functools` module, so out of the built-in namespace, because its use in Python has always remained obscure. `map()` is still there though, as it was shown to be very useful still.